# How do I use setValue:forKeyPath and valueForKeyPath

Tags: cocoa

I'm another beginner trying to get my head round Cocoa and its intricacies. I was reading DeVoe's "Objective-C". In the section on Key Value Coding there are some examples of `setValue:forKeyPath:`. Somehow, try as I might I cannot get it to work.

The following is the code:

```
// Bar.h
// UsingKVC
//
// Created by Stephen Ng on 2/04/12.
// Copyright (c) 2012 Nutek. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Bar : NSObject
{
    NSArray *array;
    NSString *stringOnBar;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray *array;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *stringOnBar;
@end


@interface Foo : NSObject 
{
    Bar *bar;
    NSString *stringOnFoo;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) Bar *bar;
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSString *stringOnFoo;
@end

//
// Bar.m
// UsingKVC
//
// Created by Stephen Ng on 2/04/12.
// Copyright (c) 2012 Nutek. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Bar.h"

@implementation Bar
@synthesize array;
@synthesize stringOnBar;

@end

@implementation Foo

@synthesize bar;
@synthesize stringOnFoo;

@end

//
// main.m
// UsingKVC
//
// Created by Stephen Ng on 2/04/12.
// Copyright (c) 2012 Nutek. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Bar.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

    Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    [foo setValue:@"blah blah" forKey:@"stringOnFoo"];
    NSString *string = [foo valueForKey:@"stringOnFoo"];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);

    [foo setValue:@"The quick brown fox" forKeyPath:@"bar.stringOnBar"]; 
    NSString *string2 = [foo valueForKeyPath:@"bar.stringOnBar"]; 
    NSLog(@"string2: %@",string2);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

string2 is NULL!

I do not understand this. I understand that when using `@property` all the code becomes KVC compliant. Yet it seems the key path does not work.

Answer (score 3):

`foo.bar` is nil (you haven't set a value for `bar`) so your KVC accessors will silently fail or return nil - the value for key path message is essentially decomposed into separate accessors, and if anything on the path does not exist, the path doesn't complete.

Create a new Bar object and assign it to `foo.bar`, then your key path code will work.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. I was assuming that [[Foo alloc] init] would also create the Bar object!